# Using GPS on Android APP stops

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gps

I want to measure speed using GPS.

I can start the application but if I start running the app will stop.
Why?

I´m using `Android 4.1`

This is the CODE.

**Manifest:**

```
</application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

**Main:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Context context;
    TextView output;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R
                .layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener=new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                location.getLatitude();

                Toast.makeText(context,"current speed"+location.getSpeed(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

    }
}
LOGCAT:
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                    Process: hexworx.gpstest, PID: 10258
>                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                        at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:109)
>                                                                        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:267)
>                                                                        at
>   hexworx.gpstest.MainActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:30)
>                                                                        at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:281)
>                                                                        at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:210)
>                                                                        at
>   android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:226)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Thanks for help!

Comment: can we have logcat please?

Comment: Thanks for answering:

I added the LOGCAT

Comment: Use MainActivity.this instead of context when displaying Toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the line

`Toast.makeText(context,"current speed"+location.getSpeed(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Replace the 'context' with 'this'  (without quotes)

Also location.getSpeed() is not always returning the speed.
To see if your location object has a Speed in it, check it with the following method:

```
location.hasSpeed();
```

You have to first get two different location points [two (lat, lon) pairs] from the GPS, then calculate the distance between these two points, the time to get the second update in the location (second point) and then calculate the speed as:
Speed = Distance / time.

You have to take into account the accuracy of the GPS location, as bad accuracy can give very unreliable results.

The lower the accuracy number it is, the better:
you can get the accuracy as follows:

```
location.getAccuracy();
```

But before using it, because location may also not have an accuracy in it, check it as follows:

```
location.hasAccuracy()
```

Also to calculate the distance between two Location objects use this:

```
location1.distanceTo(location2); // Returns meters
```

Also in this line:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

You request updates every 0ms and/or every 0 meters. Getting too frequently the location update is very unreliable plus it can cause bugs to your app. 
Replace this line to:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,2000,3.0f,locationListener);
```

so that you get updates every 2 seconds or every 3 meters (whichever comes first).